# How send value to a ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

Dear all,
In PHP we send value to another page using GET method.Like: http://localhost/abc.php?val=123
where abc.php take the value using $_GET['val'] and do the necessary.Now i need to do the same task in asp.... send value to a stand alone ASP.NET page [not from a ASP page] and after taking the value do the necessary.Now,How can i send a value to a asp.net page in the same way and receive the value into that page?pls help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way.  You can send the same query string to your aspx page `http://localhost/abc.aspx?val=123` then access the code using the `Request.QueryString` property.

```
string queryStringValue = Request.QueryString["val"];
```

Answer (score 2):

for c#

```
string myval=Request.QueryString["val"];
```

for vb.net

*FIXED, thanks to kyle*

```
Dim myval As String
myval=Request.QueryString("val")
```

Comment: Doesn't VB not use semi colons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<%= Request.QueryString["val"]%>`